# Explorer 11 can't remove USE element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, snap.svg

I'm use snapsvg library; Remove `<use>` element in IE11 doesn't work; How i can fix it?

```
c = Snap(400, 620);
c.rect(0, 0, 400, 620).attr({
    fill : 'white',
    stroke : 'black'
});

var pattern25x25;

 var createDiodePattern = function () {
        var p = c.group(),
            selectedColor = "#ff6900",
            fillColor = "#b7b7b7";

        p.add(c.circle(12, 12, 30, 30).attr({fill: '#FFFFFF', stroke: '#FFFFFF', 'stroke-with': '1', opacity: '0.1'}));
        p.add(c.rect(0, 0, 25, 25).attr({fill: fillColor, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-with': '2'}));
        p.add(c.rect(3, 5, 5, 2).attr({fill: '#FFDE00', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-with': '1'}));
        p.add(c.rect(16, 5, 5, 2).attr({fill: '#FFDE00', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-with': '1'}));
        p.add(c.circle(12, 12, 3, 3).attr({fill: '#FFFFFF', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-with': '1'}));
        pattern25x25 = p.toDefs();

    };
createDiodePattern();

var items = [];
for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    var el = pattern25x25.use().attr({
        x: i * 30,
        y: i * 30
    });

    c.append(el);
    items.push(el);
}
items.map(function(el){
    el.click(function(){
       el.remove();
    });
})
```

[Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/TWBNE/166/)

Comment: Always put all of the relevant markup and code **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: I agree. I still prefer not to have reams of code here

Comment: @mplungjan: That's the call the SE management have made. Self-contained questions.

Comment: @mplungjan: Anyway, let's remove these, they're outdated now. :-)

Comment: But I love it when people have a nice reduction that fits in one screen... with a running jsfiddle, even better! We too often see poorly asked from new users. Too bad I can't help because I never heard of Snap, but a well asked question makes me want to play with it...

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yeah, same position I'm in. :-)

Comment: Works fine for me in IE11 (and Chrome).

Comment: Just to add, it may be worth clarifying what happens for you, and if there is any error in the console.

Comment: can't remove more then one element in IE 11; console is without any notification;

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 7(32bit,64bit) IE 11.0.9600.17126IS;  Works fine in Windows 8.1(64bit) IE 11.0.9600.17126